# Emacs term in character mode still catching my keymap

Tags: keymap, term

I have the following code in my `init.el`

```
(defun my-foo (arg)
  (interactive "^p")
  (message "We got hit")
  )

(defvar my-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map (kbd "C-r") 'my-foo) map))

(define-minor-mode my-mode :keymap my-mode-map ())
(defun turn-mode-on () (my-mode +1) )
(define-globalized-minor-mode my-global-mode my-mode turn-mode-on)
(my-global-mode t)
```

In it, I define a global mode with a keymap so that <kbd>C-r</kbd> displays the message "We got hit". If I open Emacs's `term` and hit <kbd>C-r</kbd> **in character mode** I get the message "We got hit"!

I was under the impression that in character mode Emacs just relays the keys that I press to the shell without interpreting them. Is this not the case? How can I fix this while still maintaining my global keymap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor mode keymaps take precedence over major mode keymaps (i.e. the 'local' keymap).  When `term-char-mode` is called it sets the local keymap to `term-raw-map`, and your minor mode map therefore has precedence over that.

Note that `C-r` is not reserved for minor mode use (nor for major mode use), so there's no convention saying that things ought to work the way you're wanting them to work. See `C-h i g (elisp)Key Binding Conventions`

> How can I fix this while still maintaining my global keymap?

To be clear, it's *not* the global keymap; it's a minor mode keymap.

I would suggest not binding `C-r` in a minor mode keymap.  If you bind `C-r` in the actual global keymap, you won't encounter this problem.

If you're adamant, then you could perhaps use https://stackoverflow.com/a/22863701 and filter based on `(term-in-char-mode)`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain. Things are clearer to me now.